# Call Arduino method from Android and read the binary response

Tags: android, arduino

I'm trying to make an Android Application which can request something from an Arduino and read the response.
The Arduino has already a sketch preloaded with methods like

```
void logGPSData()
```

in a class defined like:

```
class CAppLogger : public CApp, public CDataLogger
{
    public:
```

My application has already a socket opened to the Arduino but How should I call that method? I need to instantiate CAppLogger class in Android and then call its logGPSData() method? If so, How can I instantiate it on Android side? I mean, How Android will know about it?

The output of the Arduino is binary. How should I read it? just read the output and convert it to string?

Thanks in advance! Guillermo.

Comment: `The Arduino has already a sketch preloaded`. Do you mean 'an app on the Arduino has already ...'? Is it your app? `My application has already a socket opened to the Arduino`. Do you mean 'opened to my app on the Ardino`?

Comment: @greenapps With "The Arduino has already a sketch preloaded" means a sketch is uploaded to the Arduino and I don't want to modify it, I just want to interact with it. With "My application has already a socket opened to the Arduino" means I have an Android application which scan bluetooth devices, and connects to the Arduino successfully so I can "talk to it" just don't know how.